# C# ignored MapRoute using Url.Action

Tags: c#, routes, maproute

I created a custom `MapRoute` to handle a specific case. I created it in `Program.cs` in this way:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute("another", "{anotherId}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

It works fine when I try to navigate using address bar. The problem is when I try to create url using `Url.Action`:

```
Url.Action(menu.Action, menu.Controller, new { anotherId = menu.AnotherId })
```

The result is an URL with `anotherId` as query string instead of url parameter. I realy don't undestand where is the problem?